# Flexbox wrap specific content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I get the `content` section to wrap nicely to the right of the image using flexbox?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /* we force a wrap so textarea is in the next line*/
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
textarea {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-left:80px; /* use margin to adjust, change this value depending the icon and image width */
}
img {
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    x
  </div>
  <!-- better remove the div around the image, it's useless and avoid having a white space issue -->
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>When this text is long it goes to the next line and it doesn't wrap nicely. It should stay right of the image</div>
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css need to be changed, look at the new code bellow:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /* we force a wrap so textarea is in the next line*/
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
}
textarea {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-left:80px; /* use margin to adjust, change this value depending the icon and image width */
}
img {
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    x
  </div>
  <!-- better remove the div around the image, it's useless and avoid having a white space issue -->
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>When this text is long it goes to the next line and it doesn't wrap nicely. It should stay right of the image</div>
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display: grid` to achieve your layout.
Example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10px 50px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 0 10px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

textarea {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3
}

.close {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="close">
    x
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>When this text is long it goes to the next line and it doesn't wrap nicely. It should stay right of the image</div>
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```